# How to stop Cocoapods from importing private Headders in umbrella

Tags: c, swift, cocoapods

my problem is, that every time I run pod install oder pod update, my umbrella.h reloads and imports all headers in my project. But this causes Compiling errors. I only need the umbrella to Import a few public Headers, but pod install changes all my Headers to public and imports all of them in my umbrella.h

Is there a way to stop the auto reloading of the umbrella.h, or a way to ignore the project Headers and only import the public ones.

It's a Flutter plugin so when I start the Flutter app from Android studio it automatically runs pod install and  is no longer able to compile the plugin.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
I needed to set all private Headers in the .podspec with: 
s.private_header_files = 'path', 'path2' ...

It looks like 'pod install' sets all Headers to public as standard.